# Java methods not working properly in certain directories

Tags: java

```
   int[] arr = new int[4];
   Arrays.fill(arr, 4);
   Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I was solving a problem and few of the methods were not recognized. I felt that posting the entire code wasn't necessary so I created a program for those specific methods. They were still unrecognized.

As far as I can imagine, this can be an issue with my vs code. The code works fine in other directories. Any suggestions?

Java version: java 18.0.1.1

[image]

I have tried cleaning the workspace but the issue persists in the directory.

Comment: You have *another* Arrays class in your directory which has priority over `java.lang.Arrays` when you use simple name Arrays. To resolve this conflict either rename your *other* Arrays class, or use full package name `java.util.Arrays.fill(..)` (same about `stream`).

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a naming conflict. You have a class called `Arrays` in the same package which conflicts with the `java.util.Arrays` class you're trying to use.

Get rid of the import statement and use the fully qualified class name instead:

```
java.util.Arrays.fill(arr, 4);
```

Or use a fully qualified import:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
// ...
Arrays.fill(arr, 4);
```

Or even a static import if you're into that sort of thing:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.fill;
// ...
fill(arr, 4);
```

Comment: This is also another reason to avoid the `import java.util.*;`, as `import java.util.Arrays;` would have correctly resolved the methods.

Comment: And, I was blaming VS Code for no reason. Thank you for pointing out the conflict. That Arrays.java is actually empty. I must have created it while using quick fix of VS code. Well, I guess I was indeed blaming VS code for a reason.